# Drop down list in Excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

In Excel 2010, I am adding a drop down list control to a worksheet. The data I want to show in the list are in range A1:C1. After assigning the input range of the control to A1:C1, I only see one item in the list (which belongs to cell A1).
If I change the input range to point to A1:A3 I see 3 items in the list. I think Excel assumes that all cells in list input range should be in one column.

My question is how to setup the input range of a drop down list to get data from cells in one row (i.e A1:C1)?

Comment: FYI, data validation will accept a column range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel requires the options from a list to be in a single column. I would suggest creating a single column of data on another sheet or far below the data in the same sheet and then reference those cells.